# Facebook Open Graph with Wordpress [Not Working]

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have been trying to fix the wordpress website for a while, so the picture with title and everything needed shows up when it is shared on facebook. However, for some reason, nothing works. For example, this is one page from the website:

http://www.economicswire.net/weak-peso-worries-argentina.html

When I try to debug it using the facebook debugger, first time I click on debug, this shows up:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdDc8.png

But, when i click on "Scrape again" this shows up:

https: //i.stack.imgur.com/steM0.png (please just add it together, I can't post it as link, only one allowed)

I really have no idea how to fix it. Anything I do, changing the plugin, nothing works. I have currently using the Facebook Open Graph, Google+ and Twitter Card Tags Plugin.

If someone has any ideas how to overcome this, please help.
I have also researched thousands of other questions regarding this, but nothing helps. I have read that gZip compression may have something to do with it, but I don't know how to disable it for facebook and I have other websites with it enabled, working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set stuff in your html head. look at these for example

```
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="123456789">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://example.com/page.html">
<meta property="og:type" content="website">
<meta property="og:title" content="Content Title">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://example.com/image.jpg">
<meta property="og:description" content="Description Here">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Site Name">
<meta property="og:locale" content="en_US">
<meta property="article:author" content="">
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I already have that. The plugin ads it up in the head, as well as includes the Open Graps in <html> tag.

But for some reason it does not seem to work

Answer (score 0):

Try [Yoast SEO](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/). They very well implement generation of Facebook Open Graph tags.

Comment: I have just tried it out, when I look in the source code, I can't find anything that may cause the problem. But it does not work :(